# Mootools add class to container by number of childs

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I want to add a class for a container element by the number of child items. But my code ads only a class for the first container and that is added wrong.

This is what I trying to do:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <div id="container" class="add class here for example col3">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div id="container" class="add class here for example col1">
   <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I wrote this code for a case when the container has only one child but it doesn't work.
This ads the col1 class to the first container which has 3 children :(

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var children = $('container').getChildren('div.child');
    if(children.length = 1) {
      $('container').set('class', 'col1');
    }
});
```

So I'm stuck here.

Comment: your markup is not valid - ID must be unique across the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that you're assigning the same ID to all your containers. Try something like this :

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){
    $$("div.container").each(function(item, i){
        var childCount = item.getChildren("div.child").length;
        item.addClass("col" + childCount);
    });​​​​​​​​
});
```

HTML :

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>​
```

See it working here : http://jsfiddle.net/kSVL5/

Comment: Thanks, probably I'm getting tired, I can't belive I missed that I added the same ID to multiple elements. Oh and you added an extra closing to the inner function.

Comment: @YannisDran Works just fine to me. Open up your console to see it, it doesn't actually do anything visible on screen.

Comment: could you please give me an clue? I don't know what to look for there.

Comment: @YannisDran I updated the JSFiddle to show it more clearly : http://jsfiddle.net/DsyVP/2/

Comment: nice. In your fiddle shouldn't be like this: first and fourth box color red, second be yellow and third be blue? I only see 1st,2nd,3rd being blue and 4th being red.